# Horizontal scroll div inside a div displayed as a table

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a webpage that has two columns. I break the columns into 2 divs with the id **right** and **left**. These two columns are inside a div with the id **row** and that div is inside a div called **table**

```
<div id="table">
   <div id="row">
      <div id="left">
      </div>
      <div id="right">
      </right>
   </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is designed so that I have two columns.

```
            #table
            {
                display:table;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #row
            {
                display:table-row;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #left
            {
                display:table-cell;
                width: 50%;
            }
            #right
            {
                display:table-cell;
                width: 50%;
            }
```

That works just fine. Now inside my left column, I want a div that can horizontally scroll images, but I don't want the column **left** to change width. I want to keep **right** and **left** at 50% of the screen.

Any help on how to create a sub div inside the **left** div that allows for horizontal scrolling of images would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You mean scroll like a slideshow or simply a horizontal scroll bar when the image is larger than the div width?

Answer (score 1):

I changed your css style to remove table and use float instead:

```
        #table
        {
            width: 300px;
        }
        #row
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #left
        {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #right
        {
            width: 50%;
            float: right;
        }
```

And add overflow:auto in whatever div you want it to render scrollbar. I assume you have a width defined somewhere.

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6ry6/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use:

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

If the sub div is bigger, a scrollbar will appear.